# Groupby regular expression Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

Let us suppose I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
val df2 = Seq({"A:job_1, B:whatever1"}, {"A:job_1, B:whatever2"} , {"A:job_2, B:whatever3"}).toDF("values")
df2.show()
```

How can I group it by a regular expression like "job_" and then take the first element to end in something like :

```
|A:job_1, B:whatever1|
|A:job_2, B:whatever3|
```

Thank a lot and kind regards

Comment: I do not get "How can I group it by a regular expression like "job_" and then take the first element to end" What are you trying to do? On which column are you trying to groupby? What is the aggregation function you would like to do?

Comment: Why don't you transform the Json to a regular DataFrame?`val df2 = Seq(("A:job_1, B:whatever1"),("job_1, whatever2"),("job_2, whatever3")).toDF("A","B")``|A||B||job_1||whatever1|
|job_2||whatever3|` and them `.groupBy(A)`

Comment: @BlueSheepToken You are right, I did not take into account that I already had a dataframe into one column. The purpose of the code should be to do mini-dataframes of same "job_" and then just pick the first one.

Comment: I was thinking on doing that @PabloLópezGallego but in the truth my string type rows have many fields  so it is better to do it using the string rows.

Comment: @Borja_042, can you create a new colum for the groupBy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just create a new column with `regexp_extract` and drop this column !

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}

df2.
    withColumn("A", F.regexp_extract($"values", "job_[0-9]+", 0)). // Extract the key of the groupBy
    groupBy("A").
    agg(F.first("values").as("first value")). // Get the first value
    drop("A").
    show()
```

Here is the catalyst if you wish to go further in the comprehension !

As you can see in the optimised logical plan, the two following are stricly equivalent :

- creating explicitly a new column with : `.withColumn("A", F.regexp_extract($"values", "job_[0-9]+", 0))`
- grouping by a new column with : `.groupBy(F.regexp_extract($"values", "job_[0-9]+", 0).alias("A"))`

Here is the catalyst plan :

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Aggregate [A#198], [A#198, first('values, false) AS first value#206]
+- Project [values#3, regexp_extract(values#3, job_[0-9]+, 0) AS A#198]
   +- Project [value#1 AS values#3]
      +- LocalRelation [value#1]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
A: string, first value: string
Aggregate [A#198], [A#198, first(values#3, false) AS first value#206]
+- Project [values#3, regexp_extract(values#3, job_[0-9]+, 0) AS A#198]
   +- Project [value#1 AS values#3]
      +- LocalRelation [value#1]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Aggregate [A#198], [A#198, first(values#3, false) AS first value#206]
+- LocalRelation [values#3, A#198]
```

Comment: I do not understand your answer well, although it looks well.

What is exactly F?

Answer (score 1):

Transform your data to a Seq with two columns and operate it:

```
val aux = Seq({"A:job_1, B:whatever1"}, {"A:job_1, B:whatever2"} , {"A:job_2, B:whatever3"})
  .map(x=>(x.split(",")(0).replace("A:","")
    ,x.split(",")(1).replace("B:","")))
  .toDF("A","B")
  .groupBy("A")
```

I removed `A:` and `B:`, but it is not necesary.

Or you can try:

```
df2.withColumn("A",col("value").substr(4,8))
  .groupBy("A")
```

Comment: that is not a good solution because the width migh not be fixed.
Thanks for all your efforts